# Having trouble getting FineUploader's Initial File List feature working

Tags: javascript, c#, fine-uploader

I've spent too much time on this feature already. I've read the documentation, I've searched Stackoverflow. The problem I'm having is that I always get success = false and of course no files are loaded. Documentation says if it has a problem parsing any item in the response but I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what my server returns in response to the Inital Files request:

```
{{
    "uuid": "3377cc66-51d2-4e80-a695-f9018e379b7b",
    "path": "~/UploadedFiles/6f633f07-b23a-43f1-8256-f0dfe9fc9abb",
    "originalFilename": "Cut Offs.png",
    "name": "636785647541018142.png",
    "size": null,
    "thumbnailUrl": null
}}
```

On the client side I am able to retrieve each of these properties just fine. Thinking that perhaps it was choking on something else I reduced it down to just the uuid and the name as those are the only ones required but I got the same result. It didn't work and the success parameter comes in as false.

The sessionRequestComplete is firing off just fine but success is always false.

Here is what I have on the server:

```
public FineUploaderResult GetFiles(string type)
{
    List<FormDocument> documents = (List<FormDocument>) Session["IVRFiles"];

    JObject json = new JObject();

    if ( documents != null && documents.Count > 0 )
    {
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documents);

        jsonString = jsonString.TrimStart(new char[] { '[' }).TrimEnd(new char[] { ']' });
        json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    }
    return new FineUploaderResult(true, json);
```

}

Am I not returning the proper thing? Here's the constructor for FineUploader Result in case that helps.

```
public FineUploaderResult(bool success, object otherData = null, string error = null, bool? preventRetry = null)
{
    _success = success;
    _error = error;
    _preventRetry = preventRetry;

    if (otherData != null)
        _otherData = JObject.FromObject(otherData);
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out. What I was returning wasn't what I should have been. I was using that FineUploaderResult class but I don't believe I should have been. So I replaced all that json string and serialize and convert stuff to something far more simple and it worked. Here's what I have on the server now:

```
public ActionResult GetFiles(string type)
{
    List<FormDocument> documents = (List<FormDocument>) Session["IVRFiles"];

    return Json(documents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And this works just fine.